# Do wavefunctions always have to be sinusoidal in '1D particle in a box' setups?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions, time-evolution

In the ideal setup, the wavefunction should be zero at the walls because these walls are of infinite potential, i.e. the particle cannot be in that position of such a high potential (*I am trying to understand the relation between the waveshape and the actual physical situation*).

But why do figures always depict the time-invariant wavefunction in a *sinusoidal form* as can be seen on [this hyperphysics page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/schr.html)? Aren't other irregular or non-symmetric shapes allowed as long as they satisfy the boundary conditions? If no, why is that?

Comment: Hint: Are we here solving the time-independent or the time-dependent SE?

Comment: @Qmechanic Is time-invariant wavefunction not in the same direction with the time-independent SE? I am asking because I am not comfortable with these equations and their meanings. I think the figures on the webpage are for the time-independent case.

Comment: There are no other shapes because here you are finding the eigenfunction of hamiltonian and restricting those eigenfunctions to boundary conditions

Comment: @Xfce4 It satisfies the TISE because you are solving it to find that eigenfunction. i.e., after solving $\hat{H}\psi = E\psi$, you get the eigenfunction $\psi(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; the wave function does not need to be sinusoidal for the particle in a box. We can have other functions that satisfy the boundary conditions.

The reason so much focus is given to the sine waves is because those functions are wave functions for particles with definite energy. Furthermore, these functions serve as a basis to describe any other wave function. If $\psi_E(x)$ is the wave function that satisfies the Time Independent Schrodinger Equation for a particle with energy $E$ (one of those sine waves), then any wave function $\Psi(x,t)$ can be written as $$\Psi(x,t)=\sum_Ec_Ee^{-iEt/\hbar}\psi_E(x)$$

where $c_E$ are complex constants. Notice that, while $\Psi$ can be written as a sum of sine waves, $\Psi$ itself does not need to be a sine wave.

Comment: Thank you. How do we know that *sine waves ... are wave functions for particles with definite energy*? Also what would be a particle with indefinite energy and how would be its wavefunction?

Comment: @Xfce4 If we solve the **time independent** SE then the solutions are time independent, and time independent solutions are energy eigenstates. So in this case the states of constant energy are the sine waves. Then we can describe any other wavefunction as a sum of the energy eigenstates i.e. by a Fourier sum. Note that these other shapes of wavefunction are not energy eigenstates and not time independent.

Comment: This visualization may be enlightening http://www.falstad.com/qm1d/

Comment: @JohnRennie Oh, I thought "particles with definite energy" were specific particles like electrons, protons etc. and all subatomic particles in the universe does have a sinusoidal wave function. In other words, I thought an atom or molecule could have an irregular wave function in a box while an electron must always have a sinusoidal one in that same box.

Comment: @Xfce4 This treatment has nothing to do with what the particle is.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Thank you. [This link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/615440/what-does-it-mean-that-a-free-particle-has-no-definite-energy-in-quantum-mechani) answered my question.

Comment: @Xfce4 Oh ok. Interesting that it's about the free particle.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I meant it answered the second part of my question on the first comment, about the particles with and without definite energy.